# Which USB data card or Modem will be supported in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, modem

I am a new Ubuntu user from Ubuntu and I want to buy a Usb data card for my laptop. I want to know which USB Data Card Brands are supported in Ubuntu? I heard from some of my friends that they had problems in Ubuntu with

Answer (score 2):

Any data card will work with Ubuntu. A nice article I found on Internet http://neopatel.blogspot.in/2011/06/reliance-tata-photon-mts-blaze-data.html